# Получить результат выполнения отслеживаемой асинхронной функции

Tags: jest

```
describe('some test', () => {
  const obj = {
    method: async () => {
      console.log(1);
    },
  };

  const fn = async () => {
    await obj.method();
  };

  it('should toHaveReturnedWith undefined', async () => {
    const spiedFn = jest.spyOn(obj, 'method');
    await fn();

    //ok
    expect(spiedFn).toHaveBeenCalled();
    // Возможно, не тот метод юзаю (если не трудно, подскажите правильный)
    // Expected: undefined
    // Received: {}
    expect(spiedFn).toHaveReturnedWith(undefined);
  });
});
```